# Artemis warning when failed live server comes online

Tags: high-availability, activemq-artemis

I have 3 node ActiveMQ Artemis 2.11.0 cluster as live and two backups. When live fails backup is promoted as live server and everything works fine. But when I restart failed live it start as live server but i expected it to join cluster as backup. Also i got following warn in actual live server.

```
2020-06-18 10:10:42,875 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client] AMQ212034: There are more     
than one servers on the network broadcasting the same node id. You will see this message exactly
once (per node) if a node is restarted, in which case it can be safely ignored. But if it is logged 
continuously it means you really do have more than one node on the 
same network active concurrently with the same node id. 
This could occur if you have a backup node active at the same time as its live node. 
nodeID=282b5370-b11c-11ea-b25f-e28f4c3b32af
```

As per the documentation I have setup `check-for-live-server` in live server

```
 <ha-policy>
    <replication>
      <master>
         <group-name>mynode</group-name>
         <check-for-live-server>true</check-for-live-server>
      </master>
    </replication>
  </ha-policy>
```

Backup configurations

```
  <ha-policy>
    <replication>
      <slave>
         <group-name>mynode</group-name>
      </slave>
    </replication>
  </ha-policy>
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue using ActiveMQ Artemis 2.13. What version are you using?
This could depend on slave configuration. Can you also share the slave configuration?

Comment: I created a working cluster ActiveMQ Artemis 2.11 using the following commands:
`artemis create master0 --user admin --password admin --clustered --cluster-password artemis --cluster-user artemis --replicated --host localhost --no-web --port-offset 0`
...
`artemis create slave0 --user admin --password admin --clustered --cluster-password artemis --cluster-user artemis --replicated --host localhost --no-web --slave --port-offset 3` . Adding `<check-for-live-server>true</check-for-live-server>` the master doesn't fail back if the slave is live. Can you share the master log when fails back?

Comment: Please provide a way to reproduce this on the [latest release](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/download/) (2.14.0 at this point).

Comment: @JustinBertram Thanks for the interest. I have installed 2.14.0 and could not reproduce this issue.